# Assessing differences in slope of a loess (or any smoother) fit

Tags: smoothing, loess

I have continuous data for x (for example "time") and y with several groups. I would like to show/test that the slope of groupC changes over time (is positive and rises) while groups A and B do not. Below is a MRE.
I was thinking about using a GAM, but could need some inspiration of how to formulate this in R. Please note that my real data are a lot more variable than the example in case that is relevant, so it's really about using some sort of smoother and then use this as a basic for assessing differences in slope.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
data <- 
  rbind(data.frame(x=seq(1, 100), y=rnorm(100, 1, 5), group="A"),
        data.frame(x=seq(1, 100), y=rnorm(100, 3, 5), group="B"),
        data.frame(x=seq(1, 100), y=jitter(seq(1, 10, length=100)^3, 1000)/20, group="C"))

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=group)) + 
  geom_smooth() + # any smoother is fine, loess is just an example for viz
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that for some intervals of $x$ there are *no* significant differences in slope while for other intervals there *are* significant differences.  Thus, you need to tell us in more detail what you mean by "differences in slope."

Answer (score 2):

Any continuous function on a compact space can be uniformly approximated as closely as desired by a polynomial. ([Stone-Weierstrauss theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)) In this case fit a quadratic to each set and note that only C has significant linear and quadratic coefficients.

```
library(nlme)
fm <- lmList(y ~ x | group, data = data, pool = FALSE)
fm0 <- lmList(y ~ 1 | group, data = data, pool = FALSE)
Map(anova, fm, fm0)
```

and here is a plot of the points and fitted lines showing it fits well:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, col = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y  ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), method = "lm")
```

(continued after graph)
[image: screenshot]

We can alternately use a gam.  In the case of the data in the question it does not really make any difference but if the data in the question is not representative of your actual problem it may be useful.

```
library(mgcv)
Map(\(g) summary(gam(y ~ x, data = data, subset = group == g)),
  unique(data$group))
```

### Update

Have added an ANOVA to lm model and added a gam alternative.  Note that both nlme and mgcv come with R so they do not have to be separately installed.

Comment: Polynomial approximations tend to be poor for statistical modeling: polynomials are too rigid (that is, they are determined globally by tiny amounts of local information).  Consider splines instead.

Comment: Did you even read the answer???  It worked very well and is really easy to do.

Comment: It worked well *for this toy example* which was based on a polynomial!  In general, the "smoothers" referred to in the question are *not* polynomials.  Thus, you are proposing a solution that seems to work in one special textbook case but is not going to generalize well to real data.  Moreover, you still haven't answered the question: how do you propose to interpret what "differences in slope" means and how does fitting a polynomial answer that?

Comment: It works in the type of case that was illustrated and likely many more since polynomials can uniformly approximate any continuous function on a compact set.  And the best part is that it is one line of code -- two if you add the plot.  Regarding what was asked it was "show/test that the slope of group C changes over time (is positive and rises) while groups A and B do not" which is what is tested here.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem is useless for statistical analysis: the polynomial basis is just too large and cumbersome to be of any practical use.  There are excellent reasons why you don't commonly see, say, polynomials of the 77th degree used even for enormous datasets.  Indeed, the very concept of a *smoother* precludes using polynomials except locally, because a smoother is supposed to flexibly describe the data within relatively small neighborhoods in a way that is immune to whatever happens beyond them. Piecewise polynomials--splines--are the natural solution.

Comment: It shows that they are universal approximators. The `poly` function is in the base of R because polynomials are commonly used in statistics.  No one is suggesting the use of 77th degree polynomials.

Comment: Unfortunately, ridiculous polynomial degrees rapidly arise when using polynomials in an effort to smooth even modest datasets -- so implicitly, yes you are suggesting the use of such polynomials.

Comment: Obviously that was not the case here nor would it be for similar curves.

Comment: And two other points: (1) dividing up the domain as would be done with splines involves using up more degrees of freedom and so has lower power.  What that means is that you are less likely to detect differences that exist. It would be more of a last resort than the preferred approach.  (2) Furthermore the purported "problem" of intervals in your comment below the question is not a problem at all in the answer here.

Comment: I used to believe (1), too, until I tested it.  There's a reason people use splines for smoothing instead of polynomials.  The burden is on you to demonstrate why the rest of the world might be using an inferior procedure.  I can't determine what you are referring to about intervals.

Comment: You can't determine what your own comment means?

Comment: Enough of the snark, please.  I cannot determine what your response to it means.  But evidently the potential for this conversation to yield anything useful is over, so I'm bowing out.

Comment: Have added an ANOVA to the lm model and noticing the request for gam in the question have added that as well.